# How to get a unicode newline character in python?

Tags: python, unicode, comments, newline, python-unicode

The problem is when I write a java code with comment

//Comment here \u000d System.out.println("Hello");

It works as I want it to i.e The output comes out to be:

Hello

Similarly when I tried doing it on python I can't find a way to insert newline character in it's comment

i.e #Comment here \u000d print("Hello");

This doesn't work.

Comment: A note for those not familiar with Java: In Java, a `\u...` escape can occur anywhere, not just inside a string, so writing for example `int \u0041=5;` is equivalent to writing `int A=5;` I *hope* that what the questioner asks for is simply impossible in Python...

Comment: Why would you want to do this, as opposed to actually typing a newline?  Seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It is not really XY since it works in a language but doesn't in another so I just wanted to know if it was possible to add a new line character in python as a person with knowledge in python might be able to clarify that if it's possible that is all I ask the problem here is that I don't know if what happens in java in this case can be translated into python or not.